# Why does PyCharm give me warnings for "Duplicate *arg"?

Tags: python, pycharm, args, python-3.5

Using Python 3.5, I'm inserting multiple multi-dimensional lists into a MySQL Query that inserts multiple rows into a table. Here is my execution code snippet:

```
for x, y, z, i in zip(list1, list2, list3, list4):
    cursor.execute(add_related_accounts_query.format(x[0], *y, *z, *i))
```

The query works fine but PyCharm is giving me this warning:

> Duplicate *args
>
> This inspection reports discrepancies between declared parameters and
>   actual arguments, as well as incorrect arguments and incorrect
>   argument order.

If I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to fix the warning through PyCharm, it eliminates `*z, *i` and then the query no longer works.

Can someone please explain why this warning is issued if its solution breaks my script?

Comment: Which version(s) of Python are you using? Multiple `*` unpacks isn't valid syntax prior to 3.5 (see [PEP-448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)).

Comment: 3.5, edit made to question

Comment: And that's the version being used by the current project interpreter in PyCharm? And which version of PyCharm? I think full 3.5 support is only available in PyCharm 5.x.

Comment: The interpreter is 3.5 but I'm using PyCharm 4.5.4, that makes sense then if you are in fact correct

Comment: You should see if it persists after upgrading to the latest PyCharm - this is shiny new syntax, so probably isn't allowed for in earlier IDE versions.

Comment: I see, thank you @jonrsharpe and if you put down an answer I'll accept. Unfortunately I can't upgrade until everyone at my company decides to upgrade together but it's good to know that the syntax is correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm probably only expects you to pass one *args list into a function.  You could add x, y and i before expanding them and I imagine pycharm would stop complaining.

```
cursor.execute(add_related_accounts_query.format(x[0], *(y+z+i))
```

You have to take the pycharm warnings with a grain of salt though.  It's not always perfect.  It has a set of comments you can place before lines like this to force it to ignore the warning.